# Django/Python: Single quotes causing Django admin interface to throw error

Tags: python, django, unicode

I am new to django and am writing a twitter clone to learn it.

I have a model like the following

```
class message(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    date_n_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, null=True,blank=True)
    parent_2 = models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)+"_"+self.text+"_"+str(self.date_n_time)+"_"+"___"+str(self.parent_2)
```

Now, I added a message with text equal to following (quotes are part of what I entered through Django create form.

> 'prod'

I am trying to access the message object through admin interface: 127.0.0.1:8000/admin/core/message/

I get the following error message in

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 9: ordinal not in
>   range(128). You passed in message: [Bad Unicode data] (class
>   'core.models.message')

Other stack overflow answers seem to suggest this is unicode issue, but if I change test to

> "prod"

I do not get any errors.

Why am I getting the error only with single quotes? How do I catch this problem through django forms/model code, preferably at the time of saving the input form?

Comment: As soon as I submitted, I realized that model has __unicode__ function. so that explains why the error comes. But I do not know how to fix the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Python2.7 or Python3? If you are using Python2.7, use `__unicode__()`, otherwise, use `__str__()`.

Please take a look at the "`__str__ or __unicode__?`" section of this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api). For proper usage, please take a look at the docs for [`__unicode__()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#unicode) and [`__str__()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#str).

**EDIT:**
I cannot replicate your error. I can access the admin just fine. By any chance, are you using an older version of Django (older than 1.8)?
[image: Test]

Try using this instead since this is supposedly the proper way to handle unicode strings as endorsed by the Django docs.

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s_%s_%s___%s' % (self.id, self.text, self.date_n_time, self.parent_2)
```

Comment: I am using Python2.7. As I mentioned in my comment, I am using __unicode__, so thats not the issue. The way admin panel is interpreting it is the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I would try changing your unicode to the following:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'{}"_"{}"_"{}"_""__"{}'.format(self.id, self.text, self.date_n_time, self.parent_2)
```

That should return what you initially wanted, including the quotes. I would also consider combining the portion that has `"_""__"` to just `"___"`. There's no real reason to separate the underscores if they're going to be following each other.

If you don't want the quotes, simply delete them. Keep the `{}`. It's a more reliable format compared to `"%s" % (context)`

Good luck with your clone!

Comment: This works along with the answer @Wannabe Coder. Thanks!